# Changing exposure doesn't change lighting on objects in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting, rendering, game-engine

I used this method to change exposure of the scene

```
RenderSettings.skybox.SetFloat("_Exposure", 1.4);
```

However, my objects in the scene are still at the same lighting condition as with previous exposure value. How can i make unity re render lighting or re compute the lighting?

I am new to unity so apologies if this is a noob setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Unity's [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderSettings-skybox.html):

> If you change the skybox in playmode, you have to use the DynamicGI.UpdateEnvironment function call to update the ambient probe.

Try adding it after your code:

```
RenderSettings.skybox.SetFloat("_Exposure", 1.4);
DynamicGI.UpdateEnvironment()
```